# How to get stored procedure result set to other stored procedure. Or return table in function in MySQL

Tags: mysql, function, stored-procedures, return-type

My first stored procedure returns 3 values which I will use in another stored procedure. I tried like this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`db`@`%` PROCEDURE `SP_Expense`(
    flightInstanceId INT 
)
begin
    SELECT F.BaseFare, CALL SP_Orderdetail(F.fareId)  
    FROM fare;
end$$
```

but I'm getting a syntax error.

Is it possible in functions? Which is return table ?

Answer (score 0):

You cant call a stored procedure from with in a select statement.  What you are doing is trying to call a function.  [Create Fucntion](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-function-udf.html).   If I understand your question SP_Orderdetail(F.fareId) returns a table? I wonder if you could turn SP_Orderdetail(F.fareId) into a view instead?

This might help as well: [Create Stored procedure and Create function syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html)